# TabIndex doesn't work with input elements in RadWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using Telerik Rad Window to show some content. There are 4 dynamic input elements that I insert into RadWindow using jQuery script.

```
$.each(inputs, function(i, input) {
    $('#table').append('<tr id="' + input.id + '"><td>' + input.desc + '<td><td><input type="text" tabIndex="' + (i+1) + '"/></td></tr>');
});
```

For some reasons when I press Tab button, I can't focus on these elements and TabIndex doesn't work.

What might be a possible reason of these not good behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tabindex="0"
```

This will make the element focus-able by tabbing in relation to it's position in the DOM.

Trying to set the tabindices manually is almost always a bad idea.  Here is a decent article on it.

http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html